# Pyhton3.7 site-packages/markupsafe/__init__.py ERROR

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

does anyone know the following python package problem and can help me on that, I am dying here...

I installed my virtual env on my AWS ec2 server and try with wsgi to open/run the flask app.

I get an 500 return and in the error log file is following comment

```
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 mod_wsgi (pid=7836): Target WSGI script '/var/www/arpprod/ARP/bin/arpAcMain.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=7836): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/arpprod/ARP/bin/arpAcMain.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/arpprod/ARP/bin/arpAcMain.wsgi", line 34, in <module>
    from arpAcMain import app as application
  File "/var/www/arpprod/ARP/bin/arpAcMain.py", line 23, in <module>
   from arpAcServices import arpAcService_api
  File "/var/www/arpprod/ARP/bin/arpAcServices.py", line 20, in <module>
     from flask import render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for,make_response, json, Flask, send_from_directory, jsonify, Flask, Blueprint
  File "/home/ec2-user/arp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
     from markupsafe import escape
   File "/home/ec2-user/arp/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/markupsafe/__init__.py", line 10
    def __html__(self) -> str:
```

Comment: I get the same error. Guidance would be great!

Comment: I also got the same error. Any idea? Thanks!